# TI-RTOS and MSP-EXP430F5438 porting

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, rtos, freertos, texas-instruments

I want to use TI-RTOS on a experimenal board MSP-EXP430F5430 that has MSP430F5438A uC. For this I have tried to compile the driverlibs for my board. I have modified the the tirtos.mak file at MSP430DEVLIST to compile for my board. After compilation I opened a project in Code Composer for MSP-EXP430F5529LP board and modify the proprieties. My problem is that after the compilation of drivers I can't find my .lib files.

Here is my output from the console:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project gpiointerrupt_MSP_EXP430F5529LP_TI_MSP430F5529 ****

"C:\\ti\\ccsv6\\utils\\bin\\gmake" -k all 
'Building file: ../gpiointerrupt.cfg'
'Invoking: XDCtools'
"C:/ti/xdctools_3_32_00_06_core/xs" --xdcpath="C:/ti/tirtos_msp43x_2_16_01_14/packages;C:/ti/tirtos_msp43x_2_16_01_14/products/bios_6_45_02_31/packages;C:/ti/tirtos_msp43x_2_16_01_14/products/tidrivers_msp43x_2_16_01_13/packages;C:/ti/tirtos_msp43x_2_16_01_14/products/uia_2_00_05_50/packages;C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base;" xdc.tools.configuro -o configPkg -t ti.targets.msp430.elf.MSP430X -p ti.platforms.msp430:MSP430F5438 -r release -c "C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_15.12.1.LTS" --compileOptions "-vmspx --data_model=restricted --use_hw_mpy=F5 --include_path=\"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/include\" --include_path=\"D:/Projects/Code Composer/gpiointerrupt_MSP_EXP430F5529LP_TI_MSP430F5529\" --include_path=\"C:/ti/tirtos_msp43x_2_16_01_14/products/msp430_driverlib_2_21_00_08a/driverlib/MSP430F5xx_6xx\" --include_path=\"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_15.12.1.LTS/include\" --advice:power_severity=suppress --advice:power=all -g --define=ccs --define=MSP430WARE --define=__MSP430F5438A__ --diag_warning=225 --diag_warning=255 --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --silicon_errata=CPU21 --silicon_errata=CPU22 --silicon_errata=CPU23 --silicon_errata=CPU40 --abi=eabi --printf_support=minimal  " "../gpiointerrupt.cfg"
making package.mak (because of package.bld) ...
generating interfaces for package configPkg (because package/package.xdc.inc is older than package.xdc) ...
configuring gpiointerrupt.xe430X from package/cfg/gpiointerrupt_pe430X.cfg ...
generating custom ti.sysbios library makefile ... 
generating custom ti.sysbios.family.msp430 Hwi stubs ... 
Starting build of library sources ...
making D:/Projects/CODECO~1/gpiointerrupt_MSP_EXP430F5529LP_TI_MSP430F5529/src/sysbios/sysbios.ae430X ...
gmake[1]: Entering directory `D:/Projects/CODECO~1/gpiointerrupt_MSP_EXP430F5529LP_TI_MSP430F5529/src/sysbios'
cle430X C:/ti/tirtos_msp43x_2_16_01_14/products/bios_6_45_02_31/packages/ti/sysbios/BIOS.c ...
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `D:/Projects/CODECO~1/gpiointerrupt_MSP_EXP430F5529LP_TI_MSP430F5529/src/sysbios'
Build of libraries failed.
C:/Users/DEVELO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/make15088-1.sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
gmake[1]: *** [BIOS.obj] Error 2
gmake: *** [D:/Projects/CODECO~1/gpiointerrupt_MSP_EXP430F5529LP_TI_MSP430F5529/src/sysbios/sysbios.ae430X] Error 2
error: xdc.cfg.SourceDir: "C:/ti/xdctools_3_32_00_06_core/packages/xdc/cfg/SourceDir.xs", line 209: xdc.cfg.SourceDir : Build of generated source libraries failed: exit status = 2:

js: "C:/ti/xdctools_3_32_00_06_core/packages/xdc/cfg/Main.xs", line 160: Error: Configuration failed!
gmake.exe: *** [package/cfg/gpiointerrupt_pe430X.xdl] Error 1
gmake.exe: *** Deleting file `package/cfg/gpiointerrupt_pe430X.xdl'
gmake.exe: *** [package/cfg/gpiointerrupt_pe430X.xdl] Deleting file `package/cfg/gpiointerrupt_pe430X.h'
gmake.exe: *** [package/cfg/gpiointerrupt_pe430X.xdl] Deleting file `package/cfg/gpiointerrupt_pe430X.c'
js: "C:/ti/xdctools_3_32_00_06_core/packages/xdc/tools/Cmdr.xs", line 51: Error: xdc.tools.configuro: configuration failed due to earlier errors (status = 2); 'linker.cmd' deleted.
gmake: *** No rule to make target 'configPkg/linker.cmd', needed by 'configPkg/compiler.opt'.
gmake: *** No rule to make target 'configPkg/linker.cmd', needed by 'configPkg/compiler.opt'.
gmake: Target 'all' not remade because of errors.

**** Build Finished ****
```

Could you give me any guidance?

Comment: What have you done to try to debug the line "C:/Users/DEVELO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/make15088-1.sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string"

Comment: That file doesn't exist